# Want to overload Button style

Tags: android, styles

I want to overload how an android `Button` looks, except I want to overload only one attribute i.e. the `android:background`. I know I could write something like:

```
<style name="App_TextButtonStyle" parent="???">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/filled_roundededges_nostroke</item>
</style>
```

Where `parent="???"` specifies which style I inherit from. My question is which style should I inherit from do that I get everything from the android default style for buttons and just define a new background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly for future visitors, I found a solution to the problem:

```
<style name="App_TextButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/filled_roundededges_nostroke</item>
</style>
```

`@android:style/Widget.Button` references the default style of the button in the currently selected theme. You could also use the holo widget button style `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button` (available since api 11).

You might want to look in `<android-sdk-install-folder>/platforms/android-XX/data/res/values` for the files `styles.xml` and `themes.xml` to check out all styles android uses for a given platform version.

Comment: How did you get your theme to use this style though? Adding this hasn't worked for mine: <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/App_TextButtonStyle </item>.

Answer (score 1):

I have used style for buttons without specifying "parent" attribute

```
<style name="BigButtonStyle">
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/backbutton</item> 
  <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">8pt</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  <item name="android:layout_margin">10pt</item>
</style>
```

I think it could be enough for you to define your style without "parent".

Comment: My problem is how do I decide what theme colors are currently being used? I mean, in a light theme a white button may look good but in a card theme like 4.0's a white button is going to look odd. I want to be able to just overload on attribute while the rest would depend on the current theme.

Comment: This is the closest, even if far from ideal, solution I've found to the problem.